# Emacs Interactive-Haskell repl non-response if either the cabal or working directory set to project directory

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, ghci

I'm running into odd behavior with the Interactive-Haskell repl in `emacs`. When I source a file, the `emacs` mini buffer shows a series of interactive prompts:

```
Start a new project named 'myproject'?
Cabal dir (guessed from myproject.cabal):
Build target (empty for default):
Set current directory:
```

If I leave either the cabal directory or the current directory to the default value of the project directory, the repl is unresponsive. I get a lambda prompt in the interactive Haskell window, I can type, but when I press enter, it never evaluates. The cursor stays on the same line as if I did not press enter at all.

If I change both of those directories to some path other than my project directory, then the repl behaves normally and evaluates expressions as expected.

Comment: Can you post a minimal `~/.emacs` file that allows you to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Does this problem occur when running in a directory with a 'myproject.cabal'? If so, have you tried running it without the cabal file?

Comment: Linking to reported issue: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/876

Comment: I am aware of a potential problem ("stuck-mode") when using evil. If you use evil, please check out https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/3271

Comment: thanks, I'm not using evil

Comment: I've read that this issue as reported in the link posted by @GracjanPolak has been closed by the following pull-request https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/pull/1116/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a known bug.** and a good catch!

The pull request https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/pull/1116/files solves it.